# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{g(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $g \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $g(n)=0$, if $n \equiv 0$ or $n \equiv 1 ~(\bmod~4)$; or  $g(n)=1$, if $n \equiv 2$ ou $n \equiv 3 ~(\bmod~4)$.

And let $s_n$ = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{g(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}$. With the help from my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864364/do-the-series-converge), we know the series is convergent.

By QC_QAOA's answer:

> We have
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty
> > \frac{(-1)^{g(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}>>{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}+\cdots$$
>
> Now, note that for for $n\equiv 2\ (\text{mod}\ 4)$ we have the terms
>
> $$\cdots-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+3}}-\cdots$$
>
> $$\cdots-\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+\frac{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+3}}{\sqrt{(n+2)(n+3)}}$$
>
> That is, the sum can be rewritten as
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{g(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n(2n+1)}}$$
>
> But we see that the term in this sum is decreasing. We conclude by the
> alternating series test that the sum converges

The obstacle I encontered lies in the last equality. If we consider the lhs as $s_n$ and rhs as $t_n$, the equality holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but only when $s_{2n+1} = t_{n}$. Since we are dealing with a conditional convergent series, then it is not always true that if $t_{n}=s_{2n+1}$ converges, then $s_n$ also converges.

My question finally is: **how can I overcome this obstacle and complete this proof?**

What I thought of doing?

- Let $L$ be the limit of $t_n$, let $j\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\varepsilon >0$ and consider $s_{2n+1+j}$. We must prove for all $j$ that $|s_{2n+1+j}-L|\leq \varepsilon$. By triangle's inequality, $$|s_{2n+1+j}-L|= |s_{2n+1+j}-s_{2n+1}+s_{2n+1}-L|\leq |s_{2n+1+j}-s_{2n+1}|+|s_{2n+1}-L|\leq\varepsilon$$

the $|s_{2n+1}-L|$ part we can easily choose a $n_0$ and make it less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq n_0$, since we know it converges. But my problem with this way of trying to overcome the obstacle lies in the $|s_{2n+1+j}-s_{2n+1}|$ part.

Let me know of any mistakes, I sinceraly thank you.

Comment: It can be shown that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nn^{-c}$ where $0 < c \le 1$ and $a_n=a_{n+m}$ for all $n$ (i.e., $a_n$ has period $m$) converges iff $\sum_{i=1}^ma_i = 0$. This is the case $c = 1/2, a_{1..4} = -1, -1, 1, 1$. Don't know if I should submit this as an answer or another question. Or neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

$$s_n=\frac{(-1)^{g(n)}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

$$t_n=(-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n(2n+1)}}$$

We have that

$$s_{4n+2}+s_{4n+3}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+3}}=-\frac{\sqrt{4n+2}+\sqrt{4n+3}}{\sqrt{(4n+2)(4n+3)}}=t_{2n+1}$$

$$s_{4n+4}+s_{4n+5}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4n+5}}=\frac{\sqrt{4n+4}+\sqrt{4n+5}}{\sqrt{(4n+4)(4n+5)}}=t_{2n+2}$$

Also

$$s_1=1$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (s_{4n+2}+s_{4n+3}+s_{4n+4}+{s_{4n+5}})=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (t_{2n+1}+t_{2n+2})=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty t_n$$